# Proper `If Condition` and proper use of `Loop Structure` in Excel-VBA

Tags: vba, excel

My Workbook has three sheets, Namely; `Questions`, `Answers` and `Incorrect Mappings`.

In **Questions** Sheet:
`Column A` is `Question_Id`.

`Column B`: `Answer_Type` has value among : **True/False**, **One another**, **Multi item**, **CheckBoxes**, **Event**.

`Column C`: `Answer_Id` (One or More 'Numeric Values') separated with Semicolon.

In **Answers** Sheet:

`Column A` is `Answer_Id`.
(Few or all Answer IDs of `Questions` sheet will be listed here, each on a single row).

`Column B` is `Frequency`; which has values such as:

**Event Based**, **Yearly**, **Half Yearly**, **Quarterly**.

The Questions and Answers sheet are linked on `Answer_Id` column.

[image: Questions, Answers and Observations Sheet]

Requirement:
If any Question Id has 'Answer Types' such as True/False, One another, Multi item, CheckBoxes; then Answer Id's against it in 
`Answers` sheet should not have frequency `Event Based` against such Answer_Id.
i.e. If `Answer_Type` is 'Event' then only, frequency against it should be **Event Based**

The incorrect mappings in `Questions` sheet should be sent to `Incorrect Mappings` sheet as hyperlinks to 'Questions' Sheet.
I've written the following code:

```
Dim shname, strstr, strErr, stString As String
Dim stArray() As String

Dim AnsIds1 As Range
Dim celadr, celval, AnsId1, AnsId2, questionType As Variant

Dim LastRow, LastRowSheet2 As Long
LastRow = Sheets("Questions").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
LastRowSheet2 = Sheets("Answers").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row


For Each questionType In Worksheets("Questions").Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
    celadr = questionType.Address
    celval = questionType.Value
    If Len(celval) >= 1 Then
        If InStr(1, ("TRUE/FALSE,ONE ANOTHER,MULTI ITEM,CHECKBOXES,"), UCase(celval) & ",") >= 1 Then
        For Each AnsIds1 In Worksheets("Questions").Range("C2:C" & LastRow)
            stString = AnsIds1
            stArray() = Split(stString, ";")
            For Each AnsId1 In stArray()
                For Each AnsId2 In Worksheets("Answers").Range("A2:A" & LastRowSheet2).Cells

                    If Trim(AnsId1) = Trim(AnsId2) Then
                         If Trim(UCase(AnsId2.Offset(0, 1).Value)) = "EVENT BASED" Then  'Is this If condition should be changed to something else?
                         AnsIds1.Interior.Color = vbRed
                            celadr = AnsIds1.Address
                            Sheets("Questions").Select
                            shname = ActiveSheet.Name
                            Sheets("Incorrect Mappings").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = AnsId2 & " Should not have Event based frequency"
                            strstr = "'" & shname & "'!" & Range(celadr).Address(0, 0)
                            Sheets("Incorrect Mappings").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("Incorrect Mappings").Range("A65536").End(xlUp), Address:="", SubAddress:=strstr
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        Next
        End If
    End If
Next
```

When I run the above code, I do get the mixed output (an incorrect output).

After writing the code step by step and debugging it step by step, I feel the mistake is at line commented as
    `Is this If condition should be changed to something else?` or at the line above it.

Can someone tell me, to what condition I've to change it?.

(Also, I need to change loop structure to get incorrect mappings only once in `Incorrect Mappings` sheet, but it's a second priority)

Comment: What were the values in your test? What is the output you expect? What was the output you received?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lookup to the keys on the **Answers** worksheet could be eased with the introduction of a [Scripting.Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251825.aspx) object.

```
Sub question_Check_by_Dictionary()
    Dim questionType As Range
    Dim v As Long, vAIDs As Variant, d As Long, dict As Object

    'load the dictionary with the answer types
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    With Worksheets("Answers")
        For d = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            dict.Item(CStr(.Cells(d, 1).Value2)) = .Cells(d, 2).Value2
        Next d
    End With

    'reset the Questions worksheet
    With Worksheets("Questions")
        .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
    End With

    'reset the Incorrect Mappings worksheet
    With Worksheets("Incorrect Mappings")
        .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Clear
    End With

    With Worksheets("Questions")
        For Each questionType In .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
            If Not CBool(InStr(1, questionType.Value2, "event", vbTextCompare)) Then
                vAIDs = Split(questionType.Offset(0, 1), Chr(59)) 'split on semi-colon
                For v = LBound(vAIDs) To UBound(vAIDs)
                    If dict.exists(vAIDs(v)) Then
                        If CBool(InStr(1, dict.Item(CStr(vAIDs(v))), "event", vbTextCompare)) Then
                            questionType.Resize(1, 3).Offset(0, -1).Interior.Color = vbRed
                            With Sheets("Incorrect Mappings")
                                .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0), _
                                                Address:="", SubAddress:=questionType.Address(external:=True), _
                                                ScreenTip:="click to go to rogue question", _
                                                TextToDisplay:="Question " & questionType.Offset(0, -1).Value2 & _
                                                               " should not have Event based frequency (" & _
                                                               vAIDs(v) & ")."
                            End With
                        End If
                    Else
                        questionType.Resize(1, 3).Offset(0, -1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                        With Sheets("Incorrect Mappings")
                            .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0), _
                                            Address:="", SubAddress:=questionType.Address(external:=True), _
                                            ScreenTip:="click to go to rogue question", _
                                            TextToDisplay:="Question " & questionType.Offset(0, -1).Value2 & _
                                                           " references an unknown Answer ID (" & _
                                                           vAIDs(v) & ")."
                        End With
                    End If
                Next v
            End If
        Next questionType
    End With

End Sub
```

I've added a check to ensure that the answer ID found in the **Questions** worksheet actually exists in the **Answers** worksheet.

[image: dictionary_Questions_Answer_key]